# PHP insert keys in string

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following string:

```
{"1":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari1.jpg","2":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari2.jpg","3":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari3.jpg","4":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari4.jpg"}
```

How can I  get rid of the numbers preceding "http..." and transform this same numbers in array *keys*?

Like this:

```
[0] => "http...", 
[1] => "http...", 
[2] => "http...",
```

Comment: What's inside your array at index 0 ?

Comment: At index 0 the arrays contains:
{"1":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari1.jpg","2":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari2.jpg","3":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari3.jpg","4":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari4.jpg"} )

Comment: What if you decode it using `json_decode` ?

Comment: Have already tryed it... doesn't work :(

Comment: I would recommend dumping your variables using `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` in cases like this since the former will show you the type of the values as well.

Comment: Please show us the actual code your using and show us the exact result of `var_dump()` of the variable you're trying to parse. The edit didn't make it more clear, considering what you've written in comments for the answer below.

Comment: Var_dump($images):

string(377) "{"1":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari1.jpg","2":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari2.jpg","3":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari3.jpg","4":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari4.jpg"}"

Comment: Please update your question instead of posting code in comments. You should also show us your actual code where this happens. That makes it way easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a JSON string, so you could decode it.

You could try

`$array = json_decode($string, true);`

You may also need to reindex the array so it is `0` based; so something like

`$array = array_values(json_decode($string, true));`

Comment: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: @AndréCastro - If you get that error, you're either passing in the wrong value (not the one you showed us) or your array looks different from what you showed us. The above should work with the data in your question. Demo: https://3v4l.org/Uii3q

Comment: The output of var_dump($images) is:

string(377) "{"1":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari1.jpg","2":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari2.jpg","3":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari3.jpg","4":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari4.jpg"}"

Comment: Yes i know that before i had an array because i exploded $images. But in this format maybee you can sort it out. This is the raw images variable has it comes from the database.

Comment: @AndréCastro - That's not the same as in your question. This is just a string, while the variable in your question is an array. For the above, just change it to: `array_values(json_decode($images, true));`. And for next time, we can only answer with the data you provided us. If you change that while we answer, the answers will most likely not apply anymore.

Comment: $x = array_values(json_decode($images, true));
var_dump($x);

Outputs NULL

Comment: The output you've provided doesn't seem to conform to `var_dump`, `var_export` nor `print_r`, so I'm trying my best to work out what our array really looks like.  Thanks for adding the formatting to your question, it's made it a bit easier to read, so I know my current answer is wrong, but still can't work out the actual array content.

Comment: Then `$images` doesn't contain a valid json string.

Comment: Yes, thats my guess to. I think $images is not in a valid JSON format.

Comment: @AndréCastro - You should update your original question with the new information or others might spend time answering a question that doesn't apply anymore.

Comment: This works fine on my machine `var_dump(array_values(json_decode('{"1":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari1.jpg","2":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari2.jpg","3":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari3.jpg","4":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari4.jpg"}', true)));`

Comment: @NibyNool - I don't think that is the actual data the OP has or it would have worked. This answer does 100% solve the original quesiton. Unless the OP updates the question with _all_ information about what the data looks like right now, we would just be guessing.

Comment: Agreed @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I updated the question and changed the array to the actual string that is fetched in the database.

Comment: @AndréCastro is that the string stored in the database, or have you output it via PHP?  Depending on your DB interface it may be modifying it before you get access to it in PHP.

Comment: Is the exact string stored in the database.

Comment: Ok, where you're trying to convert the string to an array can you try `var_dump($string, json_decode($string, true));` and supply us with the output (if you update the question please ensure you disclose that you have provided the output of this var_dump command)

Comment: The output is:

string(377) "{"1":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari1.jpg","2":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari2.jpg","3":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari3.jpg","4":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari4.jpg"}" NULL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180875/discussion-between-nibynool-and-andre-castro).

Answer (score 0):

you are having an array data in JSON formation. you have to use a PHP function json_decode to get an result.

```
$php_array = json_decode($your_array[0], true);
//to see your array
print_r($php_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something I think.
Look at this snippet:

```
$a=[
    0 => '{
        "1":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari1.jpg",
        "2":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari2.jpg",
        "3":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari3.jpg",
        "4":"http:\/\/localhost:8888\/classecar\/uploads\/dropzone\/ferrari4.jpg"
    }'
];
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($a[0],TRUE));
```

it returns:

```
Array
(
    [1] => http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari1.jpg
    [2] => http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari2.jpg
    [3] => http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari3.jpg
    [4] => http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari4.jpg
)
```

This will work considering that the array value is a "string" containing a json object.

A var_dump on your array will give you an exact idea on what type the array value is.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps:

```
<?php

//you might want to convert the JSON string to an array:

$json = '{"1":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari1.jpg","2":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari2.jpg","3":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari3.jpg","4":"http://localhost:8888/classecar/uploads/dropzone/ferrari4.jpg"}';

$array = json_decode($json);
var_dump($array);
// here you already have the json converted to an php array

$arrayWithoutStrangeIndexes = [];

foreach($array as $index => $content){
  $arrayWithoutStrangeIndexes[]= $content;  
}

// here is just your array with plain data
var_dump($arrayWithoutStrangeIndexes);
```

Comment: No need to iterate through the array to create a new one. `array_values()` will do the same thing.

Comment: Also, `json_decode($blah)` will decode to an object, you'd want `json_decode($blah, true)`